# Strip unicode character modifiers

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

What is the simplest way to strip the character modifiers from a unicode string in Python?

For example:

A͋͠r͍̞̫̜͌ͦ̈́͐ͅt̼̭͞h́u̡̙̞̘̙̬͖͓rͬͣ̐ͮͥͨ̀͏̣ should become Arthur

I tried the docs but I couldn't find anything that does this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
import unicodedata
a = u"STRING GOES HERE" # using an actual string would break stackoverflow's code formatting.
u"".join( x for x in a if not unicodedata.category(x).startswith("M") )
```

This will remove all characters classified as marks, which is what I think you want. In general, you can get the category of a character with unicodedata.category.

Comment: +1. But better to use `.startswith('M')` instead of `'M' in` here. As of 6.1, there are no 'M' subcategories of any categories, but there's no rule saying there can't be in the future.

Comment: @abarnert: So you're saying it's better to use something that might break in the future?

Comment: @martineau: No, it's better to use something that _will not_ break in the future. If a subcategories of the `M` category is added, it will be for combining marks. If a new `M` subcategory of some other category is added, it will not be for combining marks. So, the right rule for combining marks is `cat.startswith('M')`, not `'M' in cat`. (It's not _that_ likely to come up, because they haven't added any new subcategories that shared letters used by main categories, and emptied out the only existing one, `LC`. But there's no harm in doing the right thing, and at least potential benefit.)

Comment: After looking into it more, I'm not sure it really matters either way. To my understanding, the unicode character database has categories and subcategories denoted by single characters in the form "Xx". Thus using `'M' in` will work going into the future, because the subcategory would be 'm', and startswith will also continue to work. Startswith makes a bit more sense, because it will always be the first character; this will be the case unless the category designation fundamentally changes, and in that case, you could hardly expect the same code to work.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `r'\p{M}'` that is supported by [regex module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
import regex

def remove_marks(text):
    return regex.sub(ur"\p{M}+", "", text)
```

Example:

```
>>> print s
A͋͠r͍̞̫̜t̼̭͞h́u̡̙̞̘rͬͣ̐ͮ
>>> def remove_marks(text):
...     return regex.sub(ur"\p{M}+", "", text)
...     
... 
>>> print remove_marks(s)
Arthur
```

Depending on your use-case a whitelist approach might be better e.g., to limit the input only to ascii characters:

```
>>> s.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
u'Arthur'
```

The result might depend on Unicode normalization used in the text.

Comment: Good point on the normalization—one or more of the marks might be composed into one of the letters, in which case you'd lose that letter. But you can solve that by doing `unicoredata.normalize('NFD', s).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')`. (You might want to use 'NFKD' instead, depending on whether you expect to get things like U+2160 (`Ⅰ`) and, if so, whether you want to treat them as the compatible equivalent U+0049 (`I`) or skip them.)